# import from xml to fla error

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

i have this xml tree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<letters>
 <all>
      <explain>
          <word>slope</word>
      </explain>
      <description>
          <definition>a</definition>
      </description>
  </all>

   <all>
      <explain>
          <word>slope2</word>
      </explain>
      <description>
          <definition>b</definition>
      </description>
  </all>
</letters>
```

this is the new code on stage i have 3 dynamic text ( mydata and titleofmydata and activeletter ) and have 2 button ( a , b ) but when i click button at first time data show normaly but second time or second button fla show

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.  at
>   flash.text::TextField/set text()  at
>   glossary_fla::MainTimeline/createbtn()    at
>   glossary_fla::MainTimeline/letterclick()

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.sampler.Sample;
stop();
var n:int = 0;
var i:int = 0;
var myxml:XML;
var myxmllist:XMLList;
activeletter.alpha = .5;
var currentword:String;
var currentletter:String;
var myLoader:URLLoader= new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("eL366.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadXML);
function loadXML(e:Event)
{
    myxml = new XML(e.target.data);
    a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,letterclick);
    b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,letterclick);
function letterclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
        myxmllist = new XMLList(myxml.word.(@clas==e.target.name).@wordname);
        for each (var word:XML in myxmllist)
        {
            var btn:MovieClip = createbtn(myxmllist[i]);
            btn.x = 100;
            btn.y = 130 + n;
            addChild(btn);
            n +=  50;
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wordclick);
            i++;
        }
        activeletter.text = a.toUpperCase()
}
function wordclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var word:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    currentword = word.label;
    titleofmydata.text = String(currentword + " is :");
    mydata.text = String(myxml.word.(@wordname==currentword).@definition);
}
function createbtn(label:String):MovieClip
{
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Cooper Black',25,0xFFFFFF);
    txt.text = label;
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txt.background = txt.border = false;
    txt.selectable = false;
    var btn:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    btn.mouseChildren = false;
    btn.buttonMode = true;
    btn.addChild(txt);
    btn.label = label;
    return btn;
}
```

Comment: What problem? Be clear about what's not working.

Comment: now problem in this *function aTaShow()*  this function to add a textarea child

Comment: aTa is not a global variable, so this is undefined variable according to ataShow function

Comment: what can i do to use it the ataShow function and in loadxml function

Comment: what is the type of a variable?

Comment: I have definied all variables after import

Comment: use `trace(a);` before `activeletter.text= a.toUpperCase();` probably `a` is null object

Comment: When i click a button at first time trace be 'a'  but when click it again error happen 'error 2007'

Answer (score 1):

First of all `ataShow` function must be `ataShow(e:MouseEvent)` because you send button data to ataShow function when click to button,

second: use `description[i]` instead of `description[i-1]`

use `Array` for the `aTa` and `btn`

and try the code as follow

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.TextArea;

stop();

var btnArray:Array=new Array;
var txtArray:Array=new Array;

var ChangebtnPosition:int = 50;
var definition:Array = new Array  ;
var MydataAreaPosition:int = 580;

var myLoader:URLLoader= new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("eL366.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadXML);
function loadXML(e:Event)
{
    var myxml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var lenngth:int = myxml.children().length();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < lenngth; i++)
    {
        var btn:MovieClip = ButtonForWord(String(myxml.all.explain[i].word));
        var aTa:TextField = new TextField;
        aTa.x=100;
        aTa.y=200;
        aTa.width=200;
        aTa.height=200;
        aTa.condenseWhite = true;
        aTa.htmlText = String(myxml.all.description[i].definition);
        addChild(aTa);
        aTa.visible = false;
        MydataAreaPosition +=  40;
        btn.x = 165;
        btn.y = 165 + n;
        addChild(btn);
        txtArray.push(aTa);
        btnArray.push(btn);
        ChangebtnPosition +=  50;
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,aTaShow);
    }
}
function ButtonForWord(label:String):MovieClip
{
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Cooper Black',20,0x8b3a3a);
    txt.text = label;
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txt.background = txt.border = false;
    txt.selectable = false;
    var btn:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    btn.mouseChildren = false;
    btn.buttonMode = true;
    btn.addChild(txt);
    btn.label = label;
    return btn;
}
function aTaShow(e:MouseEvent)
{
    txtArray[btnArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget)].visible=true;
}
```

Comment: there is an error in  
aTa.move(130,MydataAreaPosition);
aTa.setSize(200, 200);
* move not a function also setsize

Comment: use `TextField` instead of `TextArea` and also use  `width` `height` properties for set textfield size and  use `x`  `y` properties for the position

Comment: thanks  now i use this function to click on letter then show words . this function is running one time only  and when click other letter nothing happen .. i want to remove old btn to create new one and removeChild(btn) is not running
**function letterclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
 myxmllist = new XMLList(myxml.word.(@clas==e.target.name).@wordname);
 for each (var word:XML in myxmllist)
 {
  var btn:MovieClip = createbtn(myxmllist[i]);
  btn.x = 100;
  btn.y = 90 + n;
  addChild(btn);
  n +=  50;
  btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wordclick);
  i++;
 }
}**

Comment: please update your question with new code for understandable, also if you want to remove old Button you can use `removeChild(btnArray[btnindex]);`

Comment: thank you mdemir but what about this
`TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
 at flash.text::TextField/set text()
 at glossary_fla::MainTimeline/createbtn()
 at glossary_fla::MainTimeline/letterclick()`

Comment: please update question with your new code then I'm trying to solve your issue